# "Sorry, this file is invalid so it cannot be displayed." with pdf files on GIthub

Tags: windows, google-chrome, github, github-pages, github-for-windows

Pdf can't display on my computer even though my friend's can.

https://github.com/GTLTFITHOU/Trainning/blob/main/Training%20Round%201/Other/L%20tutorial%20from%20SonDinh.pdf

Browser:  Google Chrome 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Pro 21H1

I can't understand why, please help me

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i use google chrome and this happed
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/QDfsZkz/Capture.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: can you view it if you download it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Those PNG images of a PDF are generated live when you view the page, thus can sometimes "Hiccup" or be affected by your browser extension/ Java blockers.

[image]

If insecure scripting is allowed you should see the PNG

[image]

**First try a page refresh** to see if it is just a temporary glitch in PDF rendering to PNG.

If that does not work then use the **<kbd>Download</kbd>** button to save as a link or to download the source PDF.